# How can run broadleaf commerce open admin at maven project

Tags: java, maven, broadleaf-commerce

I need help, I downloaded BroadLeafCommerce from git-hub through,

https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/BroadleafCommerce

,I found all of them are Jars and Pom package, I want to access open admin module pages,  So I create maven war project and call all admin module Jars as dependencies, I begin to access any page from URL but the pages appears not available for me, So, is this the correct way to run any available module?, or how can run specific module, BTW I use Tomcat web Server and NetBeans IDE.

Answer (score 4):

Broadleaf has an open source starter project found here https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/DemoSite.

1) Clone the repo
2) `mvn clean install;cd site;mvn spring-boot:run`
3) Open a new terminal and go to the repo
4) `cd admin;mvn spring-boot:run`
5) Open a browser tab and go to `localhost:8080` to access the site and `localhost:8081/admin` to access the admin